# Put more things on a bootable flash drive?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

As far as I know (and please correct me if I'm wrong) when creating a bootable flash drive, all information on the drive is erased. Will the following create a problem?

1. Adding files *after* the bootable flash drive is created
2. Moving all of the bootable flash drive files to one folder (and
   returning them to their original location when I have to boot from
   it)

Comment: Making a flash drive bootable does not necessarily have to erase the drive, it depends on how you are making it bootable and on what sort of file system it currently has installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, as long as there is enough space both of those scenarios should work alright. A bootable flash drive still has a normal filesystem and if its a writable filesystem like FAT32, NTFS or EXT, it would let you copy files in.

While the bootloader would look for specific files by location (and this should work), moving the files back and forth might mess with permissions.

It *would* be simpler to add the files to their own folder, within the file system hierachy of whatever OS it uses IMO, but taking into account these considerations, this should work

Comment: But that would depend on how the bootable image was created. If it was a block level copy of a CD/ISO, I think it would be a read-only file system.

Comment: edited to reflect that

Comment: +1 Thanks. It sounds from your answer like a bootable drive is like any other, except it has special files. If so, why would there be a special file type as iso, and iso burning software, or the Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool? We could simply have files and copy them onto the flash drive.

Comment: The USB/DVD download tool just automates the process of creating a bootable drive partition (with diskpart), formatting it to NTFS and flipping the bootable flag on the drive, and extracting and copying over the install files.

Comment: Note that commenting on an answer doesn't inform the question-asker of that comment, only the answerer (unless specified by @name).

Answer (score 0):

Deferentially it will create the problem actually system will not **copy** the hidden system file from  **flash drive to your system** 
so you have to change the option from Tool-> folder Option and in that show system files and then it will show you at that time you can copy but I am **not** pretty sure about that It will work like a Bootable Flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy files to a USB drive that was setup as a bootable one for Windows 10. Everytime I created a folder and copied some file into it, they were removed after unplugging the drive. Only files in the main folder were kept between reconnecting the USB drive.